# Batch to check if removable disks are connected. If yes, execute another command

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I know how to check if there are removable disks connected with a CMD command

```
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid, volumename, description
```

But now I would like to make a batch that checks if there's any removable disks connected, and if so, then it would execute another command or run another batch.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid, volumename, description | findstr /C:"Removable Disk"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    Rem Put commands in here to run if disk is found
) else (
    Rem Put commands in here to run if disk not found
)
```

The easiest way is to set your batch file to run on a scheduled task every x minutes - although it could take a up to that many minutes before the removable disk is "detected".